# Show that Rows are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Consider a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and define $a_{i\cdot}$ as the $i$-th row of $A$ and $a_{\cdot i}$ as the $i$-th column of $A$.

Next to this, there are pairwise disjoint index sets $I_1,\ldots, I_n\subseteq\{1,\ldots, m\}$ for some $n\in\{1,\ldots, m\}$ with following property:

Let $I\in\{I_1,\ldots, I_n\}$. For every $i\in I$, it holds

$$a_{ip}=0=a_{pi}\text{, if }p\not\in I$$
$$a_{ip},a_{pi}<0\text{, if }p\in I\backslash\{i\}$$
$$a_{ii}=-\sum_{j\in I\backslash\{i\}}a_{ij}$$

One last information is given, namely $\operatorname{rank }M=m-n$.

Now I would like to show, that the rows $(a_{i\cdot})_{i\in I}$ are linearly dependent for any $I\in\{I_1,\ldots,I_n\}$.

I tried following:

The columns $(a_{\cdot j})_{j\in I}$ are linearly dependent for any $I\in\{I_1,\ldots,I_n\}$, since for any $i\in I$, it holds

$$ \sum_{j\in I}a_{i j}=a_{ii}+\sum_{j\in I\backslash\{i\}}a_{ij}=0$$

If $i\not\in I$, then every entry is equal $0$, such that

$$ \sum_{j\in I}a_{i j}= 0$$

Given the information, that $\operatorname{rank }M=m-n$, we can define a selection $S=\{i_1,\ldots, i_n\}$, with $i_j\in I_j$ for $j\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$ and we find that the columns $(a_{\cdot j})_{j\in\{1,\ldots, m\}\backslash S}$ must be linearly independent. Especially the columns $(a_{\cdot j})_{j\in I_k\backslash\{i_k\}}$ must be linearly independent for any $k\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$.

However, I am not able to show it for the rows $(a_{i\cdot})_{i\in I}$. I think I have to use the fact, that for any other row $a_{i\cdot}$ with $i\not\in I$, there is showing up a non-zero element at $j$-th column/entry for $j\not\in I$, because of $\operatorname{rank }M=m-n$. However, I am not sure, how to prove it rigourosly or how to find the contradiction.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think, I have an idea now. Define a matrix $(a_{\cdot i})_{i\in I}$ consisting of the columns indexed by $I$. Then throw away all rows above the smallest index in $I$ and all rows below the biggest index of $I$. This matrix must have rank $|I|-1$, since any $|I|-1$ columns are linearly independent. Then this applies to the rows as well. Then the rows $(a_{i \cdot})_{i\in I}$ must be linearly independent as well, because these are the same expect for putting zeros in the entries below the lowest index of $I$ and the entries bigger than the biggest index of $I$. Is this right?

Comment: I assume wherever you say $\text{rank }M$, you actually mean $\text{rank }A$, since you have not defined any $M$. Your description in your comment presumes that the indices in each $I$ are consecutive, which is not required in the question itself, but otherwise the idea is correct. Form the matrix with just the rows and columns of $I$, and it must be of rank $|I|-1$, which applies to both rows and columns. So the number of independent rows is the same as the number of independent columns. Because the rows and columns are zero outside $I$, this does not change in the full matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!